# AspNetCore rejects preflight messages

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, ntlm

We have a HttpSys listener which should accept authentication as either NTLM, Negotiate or JWT.

Problem is that it looks like HttpSys rejects both preflight messages and messages with Bearer token (JWT)

Our listener is build like this

```
        _host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            })
            .UseUrls($"http://+:{PortNo}/")
            .UseUnityServiceProvider(IocContainer)
            .ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddSingleton(_startUpConfig); })
            .UseStartup<StartUp>()
            .Build();
```

We add CORS and Authentication to services:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("*");
        }));

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents { OnTokenValidated = context => AuthMiddleWare.VerifyJwt(context, _jwtPublicKey) };
            });
```

We run an angular application in Chrome, which is rejected with the following error message
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. "

Also any Bearer token message is rejected. Debugging reveals that our code to verify JWT bearer is never reached (AuthMiddleWare.VerifyJwt)

My guess is that HttpSys rejects any message not carrying Either Ntlm or Negotiate token. Only I have no idea how to fix that

In .net Framework we used the AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate to run the following code, which allowed OPTIONS messages and messages with Bearer token to pass through the HttpSys listener

```
    public AuthenticationSchemes EvaluateAuthentication(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
        }

        if (request.Headers["Authorization"] != null && request.Headers["Authorization"].Contains("Bearer "))
        {
            return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
        }

        return AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
    }
```

Comment: Do you call `app.UseCors()`? Do you decorate your controller/action with `EnableCors` attribute?

Comment: Yes we use app.UseCors("AllowAll"); We had not used the EnableCors attribute. Just tried it. It didn't make any difference. Debug shows we never enter the pipeline. The request never comes out of HttpSys. So a Controller Attribute would not fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have this working now. Basically the problem was that allowing all three authentication methods is not a supported scenario in Asp Net Core.

So the trick was to implement our own authentication in the pipeline.

Also see this github issue:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13135